# Dependency cycle between annotated bindings in Dagger in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, annotations, cycle, dagger

**Context**

I have an Android application written in Kotlin with use of Dagger (v. 2.27). In my tests I create real instances of some dependencies and some of those dependencies `@Inject` a `CoroutineDispatcher`.

**Goal**

Allow my tests to optionally specify a test `CoroutineDispatcher` to be used by Dagger's test component. Some tests don't need that extra configuration and they should automatically get a predefined test dispatcher.

**How**

I have a module which exposes `@BindsOptionalOf` for a `@TestIODispatcher CoroutineDispatcher`.

- When a test needs a custom dispatcher, it can manually bind it inside TestComponent's Factory.
- When a test doesn't need any custom dispatcher, it should automatically get TestCoroutineDispatcher().

```
@Module
abstract class RepositoryTestModule {
    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
    annotation class TestIODispatcher

    @BindsOptionalOf
    @TestIODispatcher
    abstract fun testIODispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher

    @Module
    companion object {

        @Provides
        @IODispatcher
        fun coroutineDispatcher(
            @TestIODispatcher testIODispatcher: Optional<CoroutineDispatcher>): CoroutineDispatcher {
            return testIODispatcher.orElse(TestCoroutineDispatcher())
        }
    }
}
```

In my test I create a TestComponent with a Factory that accepts `@BindsInstance @TestIODispatcher`.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [RepositoryTestModule::class])
interface TestComponent {
    fun inject(...)

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(
            @BindsInstance @TestIODispatcher ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher) : TestComponent
    }
}
```

I pass my custom test-only dispatcher as an argument of the factory during the component definition.

```
DaggerAppNameViewModelTest_TestComponent
  .factory()
  .create(Dispatchers.IO)
```

**Problem**

The compilation of my test fails with a [Dagger/DependencyCycle] error.

```
public static abstract interface TestComponent {
                           ^
  java.util.Optional<kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher> is injected at
      com.example.<appname>.repository.RepositoryTestModule.Companion.coroutineDispatcher(testIODispatcher)
  kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher is injected at
  ...
```

I don't quite see a dependency cycle since my `@IODispatcher CoroutineDispatcher` depends on `@TestIODispatcher CoroutineDispatcher` which is explicitly bound by the test.

My theory is that Kotlin somehow strips out the annotations and then it simply compares the bindings via types. In that case there would indeed be a cycle.

Am I missing an obvious cycle here or do I need to do something with the annotations?